# What does "ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)" mean?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by

The following SQL is from Itzik Ben-Gan that is used to generate a numbers table. What does the `order by (select null)` part mean? Thanks.

```
DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT;
SELECT @number_of_numbers = 100000;

WITH    a AS ( SELECT   1 AS i
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   1
             ),
        b AS ( SELECT   1 AS i
               FROM     a AS x ,
                        a AS y
             ),
        c AS ( SELECT   1 AS i
               FROM     b AS x ,
                        b AS y
             ),
        d AS ( SELECT   1 AS i
               FROM     c AS x ,
                        c AS y
             ),
        e AS ( SELECT   1 AS i
               FROM     d AS x ,
                        d AS y
             ),
        f AS ( SELECT   1 AS i
               FROM     e AS x ,
                        e AS y
             ),
        numbers
          AS ( SELECT TOP ( @number_of_numbers )
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT   NULL
                                                     ) ) AS number
               FROM     f
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    numbers;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) requires an `ORDER BY` clause syntactically. You cannot use it without one. `SELECT NULL` is a hack to shut up the error while not enforcing any particular order. In this case we don't need to enforce any order, so the fastest option is to use `SELECT NULL`.

The optimizer sees through this trick, so it has no runtime cost (this claim is easily verified by looking at the execution plan).

Comment: It can also be used as a statement of intent when it's not actually required. For example, in Micrsoft's training kit book "Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012", they advise adding it to a valid query as, "...if
you are really after three arbitrary rows, it might be a good idea to add an ORDER BY clause
with the expression (SELECT NULL) to let people know that your choice is intentional and not
an oversight."