# SQL Query Uniqueness with subjoin

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Help!  Here is a very simple a,b,c sample of what I need to accomplish.  I have been pulling my hair out.  I've written this before but can't get my head around it now!  So here it is, with actual and expected results demonstrated below:

```
set nocount on
declare @a table (id int, a varchar(10))
declare @b table (ref int, b varchar(10), c varchar(20))


insert into @a select 1, 'bingo'
insert into @a select 2, 'bongo'


insert into @b select 1, 'T5', 'asdfwef'
insert into @b select 1, 'T8', 'asfqwez'
insert into @b select 1, 'T6', 'qweoae'
insert into @b select 1, 'T8', 'qzoeqe'
insert into @b select 1, 'T9', 'oqeizef'
insert into @b select 2, 'T3', 'awega'
insert into @b select 2, 'T6', 'fhaeaw'
insert into @b select 2, 'T3', 'fqsegw'


select * from @a a join @b b on a.id = b.ref

-- Expected  (Uniqueness is: a’s id to b’s ref and the first b value ingoring b’s c value)
----1,bingo,1,T5,asdfwef
----1,bingo,1,T8,asfqwez
----1,bingo,1,T6,qweoae
----1,bingo,1,T9,oqeizef
----2,bongo,2,T3,awega
----2,bongo,2,T6,fhaeaw

-- Actual
----1,bingo,1,T5,asdfwef
----1,bingo,1,T8,asfqwez
----1,bingo,1,T6,qweoae
----1,bingo,1,T8,qzoeqe
----1,bingo,1,T9,oqeizef
----2,bongo,2,T3,awega
----2,bongo,2,T6,fhaeaw
----2,bongo,2,T3,fqsegw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning the correct results.  All the matching values from `@b`.

If you want the first b value, you need to do two things.  First, you need to include an ordering column in b so you know what "first" is.  Remember, SQL tables are unordered.  This is easy:

```
declare @b table (id int identity(1,1) not null, ref int, b varchar(10), c varchar(20));
```

You then have to change the inserts to insert all but the id:

```
insert into @b(ref, b, c) select 1, 'T5', 'asdfwef';
```

Now you are ready for the actual query:

```
select *
from @a a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.ref, b.b order by b.id) as seqnum
      from @b b 
     ) b
     on a.id = b.ref and b.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: And, if you really don't care which row is "first" and only want one, you can use the kludge of "SELECT NULL" in the ORDER BY clause of OVER. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10066840/10192). That way you wouldn't need the new id column in @b.

Comment: In our case, we do have a date field in which we will take the latest.  I'm coding this this morning.  I do appreciate the help!  By the way, was expecting a subquery solution to be honest, that performed a max of some sort.  Not familiar with the partition by language so looking forward to seeing this work.

Comment: In the end, I ended up with 2 temp tables, the first capturing and de-normalizing the data from the disparate system, and the 2nd table I push unique results to using a subjoin and MAX aggregate from the first table.
I still find the partition sample above provided by Gordon very helpful.  Thanks Gordon.