# How to use ROW_NUMBER with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT *
FROM My table A
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1)
```

While using this getting error as 
Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

How i can make it work.

TIA

Comment: As the erros says: you can't use column numbers in ORDER BY inside ROW_NUMBER, this only works on ORDER BY for the whole statement. Do you need ROW_NUMBER for each separate column?

Answer (score 9):

Your query makes no sense.  You are not really specifying an `order by` condition in the outer query, so why bother?

Perhaps you want to add a "row number" value to the output.  If so, then the `row_number()` belongs in the `select`, not the `order by`:

```
SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM Mytable A;
```

SQL Server does not permit constant values in `ORDER BY` -- either in a window function or in the `ORDER BY` clause.  The `SELECT NULL` subquery is a way around this.  Normally, an integer expression in an `ORDER BY` is an index, referring to the column to be ordered.  That works for the `ORDER BY` clause, but not for a window function.  SQL Server also rejects other constants.

In my experience, this does not result in an additional sort.  To the best of my knowledge, this is not documented, however.

Answer (score 3):

This can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
FROM [My table] AS A
ORDER BY RN;
```

Comment: Is your table actually `My table`? If so, this needs to be wrapped up in square brackets. If it's still not working, let me know what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use row_number() function in order by clause .you can do something like this..

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) as Rno, * FROM My table A order by rno
```

or

```
 with cte as
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) as Rno, * FROM My table A 
    )
    select * from cte ORDER BY Rno
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as RN
FROM My_table_A
ORDER BY RN;
```

Comment: @user1844634:- Are you getting an error? If yes then what?

Comment: What the select 1 means? is 1 Is the column number.? even i put it as 1,2,3,4 .. giving me the same result. I want to sort table by different columns by giving column number

Comment: @user1844634:- Yes you will receive same result for any value. Check Gordon answer where he mentioned: `SQL Server does not permit constant values in ORDER BY -- either in a window function or in the ORDER BY clause. The SELECT NULL subquery is a way around this`

Comment: @user1844634:- Also you can check [What does “ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066819/what-does-order-by-select-null-mean)