# Split value into rows based on delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Spliting the given input value from table into next row (need to split each exactly after 3rd )

### Input

```
Temp (column/Table1)
TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00 | TQR101 | CP | 5.00 | TXL101 | PC | 1.00 | SQL101 | PC | 1.00........etc
```

### Output

```
 ID          Pack    qty (columns/Table2)

TBL101       PC      1.00
COMP101      CS      1.00
TQR101       CP      5.00
TXL101       PC      1.00
SQL101       PC      1.00
```

I'm using the below code to do this but only for first row it is working

```
DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(40)
SET @Delimiter = '|'
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(temp, @Delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML)
        AS [ColName XML]
    FROM Table1
)
--INSERT INTO Table2
  -- (ID,PACK,OrderQty)
SELECT
 [ColName XML].value('/M[1]', 'bigint') As [ID],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[2]', 'VARCHAR(40)') As [Pack},
 [ColName XML].value('/M[3]', 'decimal(18,2)') As [OrderQty]

FROM CTE
GO
```

Comment: Why are you storing delimited values in single column ? Consider changing your table structure

Comment: If you insist on doing it this way, you will first have to select all 9 "columns", then UNPIVOT to make three rows (with the intended three columns) out of that one row. Look into how UNPIVOT works (eg using the UNPIVOT keyword, or using CROSS APPLY to make three rows out of one row).

Comment: give more sample with exact expected output

Comment: @Prdp : I'm not storing this is how I'm getting the values from other table, I need to divide and then store it into actual table,

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale Output values are provide in the example, if you want some other values i can edit.

Comment: add more bcoz ..what is mean by 'need to split each exactly after 3rd ?'

Comment: ok .Temp  table have only 1 record ?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale : I have added, for your consideration 3rd value means Qty values like 1.00,5.00 etc

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale : As of now it has one record but it will increase

Comment: Do you know beforehand how many fields will be packed inside the string column (eg in your example, 15 fields)? Or will it be dynamically?

Comment: dynamic. Its not fixed (main problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Version for dynamic number of fields in the string. No explanation here, if you want some ask in comments. Enjoy.

```
CREATE TABLE #dta(
    r NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #dta(r)VALUES
    ('TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00 | TQR101 | CP | 5.00 | TXL101 | PC | 1.00 | SQL101 | PC | 1.00'),
    ('TBL102 | PC | 4.00 | COMP102 | CS | 3.00 | TQR102 | CP | 6.00 | TXL102 | PC | 7.00 | SQL102 | PC | 9.00');

DECLARE @num_fields INT;

SELECT
    @num_fields=MAX(LEN(r) - LEN(REPLACE(r,'|',''))) + 1
FROM
    #dta;

DECLARE @fields_sel NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @fields_sel=STUFF((
SELECT 
 ',[ColName XML].value(''/M['+CAST((N-1)*3+1 AS VARCHAR)+']'', ''NVARCHAR(40)'') As [ID'+CAST(N AS VARCHAR)+']'+
 ',[ColName XML].value(''/M['+CAST((N-1)*3+2 AS VARCHAR)+']'', ''NVARCHAR(40)'') As [Pack'+CAST(N AS VARCHAR)+']'+
 ',[ColName XML].value(''/M['+CAST((N-1)*3+3 AS VARCHAR)+']'', ''decimal(18,2)'') As [OrderQty'+CAST(N AS VARCHAR)+']'
FROM (
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
) AS tally(N)
WHERE N<=@num_fields/3
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');

DECLARE @ca_sel NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ca_sel=STUFF((
SELECT
    ' UNION ALL SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM([ID'+CAST(N AS VARCHAR)+'])),RTRIM(LTRIM([Pack'+CAST(N AS VARCHAR)+'])),[OrderQty'+CAST(N AS VARCHAR)+']'
FROM (
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
) AS tally(N)
WHERE N<=@num_fields/3
FOR XML PATH('')),1,LEN(' UNION ALL'),'');

--SELECT @ca_sel;

--SELECT @fields_sel;

DECLARE @Delimiter NVARCHAR(40)
SET @Delimiter = N'|'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql=N'
;WITH CTE([ColName XML]) AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(''<M>'' + REPLACE(r, @Delimiter , ''</M><M>'') + ''</M>'' AS XML) AS [ColName XML]
    FROM 
        #dta
), sep_fields AS (
SELECT
    '+@fields_sel+N'
FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    up.*
FROM
    sep_fields
    CROSS APPLY (
        '+@ca_sel+N'
    ) AS up([ID],[Pack],[OrderQty])';

---SELECT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Delimiter NVARCHAR(40)', @Delimiter;

DROP TABLE #dta;
```

---

Here's an answer for when you know beforehand how many fields will be present in the string field (eg in your question, 15):

```
CREATE TABLE #dta(
    r NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #dta(r)VALUES
    ('TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00 | TQR101 | CP | 5.00 | TXL101 | PC | 1.00 | SQL101 | PC | 1.00'),
    ('TBL102 | PC | 4.00 | COMP102 | CS | 3.00 | TQR102 | CP | 6.00 | TXL102 | PC | 7.00 | SQL102 | PC | 9.00');

DECLARE @Delimiter NVARCHAR(40)
SET @Delimiter = N'|'
;WITH CTE([ColName XML]) AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(r, @Delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS [ColName XML]
    FROM 
        #dta
), sep_fields AS (
SELECT
 [ColName XML].value('/M[1]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [ID1],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[2]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [Pack1],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[3]', 'decimal(18,2)') As [OrderQty1],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[4]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [ID2],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[5]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [Pack2],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[6]', 'decimal(18,2)') As [OrderQty2],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[7]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [ID3],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[8]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [Pack3],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[9]', 'decimal(18,2)') As [OrderQty3],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[10]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [ID4],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[11]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [Pack4],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[12]', 'decimal(18,2)') As [OrderQty4],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[13]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [ID5],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[14]', 'NVARCHAR(40)') As [Pack5],
 [ColName XML].value('/M[15]', 'decimal(18,2)') As [OrderQty5]
FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    up.*
FROM
    sep_fields
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT [ID1],[Pack1],[OrderQty1]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ID2],[Pack2],[OrderQty2]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ID3],[Pack3],[OrderQty3]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ID4],[Pack4],[OrderQty4]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ID5],[Pack5],[OrderQty5]
    ) AS up

DROP TABLE #dta;
```

Result is:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║    ID1    ║ Pack1 ║ OrderQty1 ║
╠═══════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ TBL101    ║  PC   ║ 1.00      ║
║  COMP101  ║  CS   ║ 1.00      ║
║  TQR101   ║  CP   ║ 5.00      ║
║  TXL101   ║  PC   ║ 1.00      ║
║  SQL101   ║  PC   ║ 1.00      ║
║ TBL102    ║  PC   ║ 4.00      ║
║  COMP102  ║  CS   ║ 3.00      ║
║  TQR102   ║  CP   ║ 6.00      ║
║  TXL102   ║  PC   ║ 7.00      ║
║  SQL102   ║  PC   ║ 9.00      ║
╚═══════════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable time but input values which you have took can be increase or decrease, its not fixed. thats the reason I have added etc etc in the end.

Comment: @Somashekhar Updated answer for dynamic number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = N'TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00 | TQR101 | CP | 5.00 | TXL101 | PC | 1.00 | SQL101 | PC | 1.00',
        @x xml

SELECT @x = CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(@str,' | ', '</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  t.c.value('.','nvarchar(100)') as [values],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM @x.nodes('/a') as t(c)
)

SELECT  [1] as ID1,
        [2] as Pack1,
        [0] as OrderQty1
FROM (
    SELECT  rn- CASE WHEN rn%3 = 0 THEN 3 ELSE rn%3 END as seq,
            rn%3 as s,
            [values]
    FROM cte
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX([VALUES]) FOR s IN ([1],[2],[0])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
ID1     Pack1   OrderQty1
TBL101  PC      1.00
COMP101 CS      1.00
TQR101  CP      5.00
TXL101  PC      1.00
SQL101  PC      1.00
```

At first convert into simple XML. Then add `ROW_NUMBER()` with `SELECT NULL` (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066819/what-does-order-by-select-null-mean#10066840) about this trick) it will add some id to every row. Then we play with row numbers to get some sequence, so we can pivot that results.

**EDIT**

If you are using table, then make whole table an XML like:

```
DECLARE @temptable TABLE (
    Column1 nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES
(N'TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00 | TQR101 | CP | 5.00 | TXL101 | PC | 1.00 | SQL101 | PC | 1.00')

DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = (
    SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(Column1,' | ', '</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml)
    FROM @temptable
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
```

Then goes part with CTE as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. you are giving here @str value as Static, I need to get the str value from table, one column from table has value as like in the input, How should i pass table value here.

like select temp from Table1;      Here temp has the value of str

Comment: Add the table solution :)