# How can I select an interval in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql

I want a result which is like a `for (int a=0; a<10; a++) { print(a); }` in a procedural language. Thus, the result should be

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Yes, I know it is not really a declarative thing, but now this is what I really need. Maybe some windowing function could do the trick? Or a procedural query?

Comment: Depends on your database engine. If you are using SQL Server, then you can look into CURSOR or WHILE loops

Comment: @Sparrow It is t-sql, thus the database engine is Microsoft SQL Server. In my specific case, it is mssql 2016, namely the SEDE engine.

Comment: For someone with that much rep, I would expect you to be able to Google "How to write a loop in TSQL" or "How to create a list of numbers in SQL Server"

Comment: @dfundako Try this, there were no meaningful results, at least not on the first some pages of the google results, this is what I would like to help.

Comment: tsql applies to both Microsoft's SQL Server and Sybase's SQL server, so perhaps you should add the SQL Server tag to your question to be more specific. :)

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1 first from Google: "tsql generate numbers 1 to 10"  The hardest part of googling is knowing what to google.  The hardest part of knowing how to spell something is knowing how to spell it so I can look up how to spell it... Stupid Dictionary

Comment: @dfundako It is the truth. There were tremendous, in around 98% irrelevant microsoft documentation pages, there were also many hits for BETWEEN queries, but nothing I am looked for.

Comment: @xQbert I would say that was correct 10 years ago. Today, you can Google something just as if you were talking and get the correct results the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @xQbert Extreme well solution, thank you!

Comment: @defundako fair enough but if you search for "How can I select an interval in t-sql?" you're not going to get much.  interval is not the key word here.  generate numbers would be.

Comment: The article is an entirely different question, but the code provided shows a pretty clever way of doing this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066819/what-does-order-by-select-null-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like that:

```
with cte as (
    select 0 as t
    union all
    select t + 1 from cte
    where t < 9
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: `t <=9` but close enough :P  (Recursive CTE for the win!)

Comment: I agree with you, but in this case you will have sequence from 0 to 10, because condition stay before increment will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the accepted answer, also this, more procedural solution works:

```
DECLARE @n INT=-10;
DECLARE @loop TABLE (n INT);

WHILE @n <= 10
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @loop VALUES(@n);
  SET @n += 1;
END;

SELECT * FROM @loop;
```

Answer (score 1):

@xQbert gave a wonderful [link](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) with a more fine solution, although it uses an undocumented feature what may later disappear from the MS-SQL. My current experiments show, in MS SQL 2016 it works:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) 
  FROM [master]..spt_values ORDER BY n;
```

According to the refered link, the `[master]..spt_values`

> is used by internal stored procedures for various purposes. Its use
>   online seems to be quite prevalent, even though it is undocumented,
>   unsupported, it may disappear one day, and because it only contains a
>   finite, non-unique, and non-contiguous set of values.

Comment: I've see folks get a little nutty over using spt_values.  Personally I see no issue with it.  Certainly more performant that loops and recursion, especially with larger ranges.  For N > 2500 and < 6.5MM just do the following Select Top 10000 n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) from [master]..spt_values n1,[master]..spt_values n2
 ...  AND IF that (doubtful) day ever comes when MS retires spt_values, it would be an easy fix.   In any case +1