# Find out the ranges of numbers that are monotonically increasing

Tags: mysql, sql

I found this question on leetcode:

> Given a table name "numbers" with 1 column name "id" like this: 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 7, 8
> Write an SQL script to find out the ranges of numbers that are monotonically increasing. Answer: 2-5, 1-4, 2-8

My solution is what follows, which is quite long with a lot of subqueries since I'm new with SQL, I'm only comfortable with `select, from, where, group by`. Could you please let me know if my query is correct? I believe that there exists a simpler query than my solution, but for the moment I don't know how to do it. Could you please let me know how?

```
with x as
select current, increasing as a, lead(increasing,1,0) as b
from 
(
    (select current, (case when current > before then 1 else 0 end) as increasing
    from 
        (select id as current, lag(id,1,0) as before
         from table numbers)
     )
)

select t1.start, t2.end
(select current as start, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
from x
where a=0 and b=1) t1
inner join 
(select current as end, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
from x
where a=1 and b=0) t2
on t1.numrow = t2.numrow
```

Thanks.

Comment: `OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` looks rather strange. Why not simply uswe `over()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is most likely interview question, so standard SQL applies

Comment: [dejavu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953871/write-an-sql-script-to-find-out-the-ranges-of-numbers-that-are-monotonically-inc)

Comment: yes, I posted 5 hours ago. I edited it but it couldn't be re opened to receive an answer, so I decided to post it again

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I saw it here so I applied it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066819/what-does-order-by-select-null-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question, your data needs to have an ordering column.  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets, so there is no ordering without such a column.

Use `lag()` to determine where a monotonically increasing group starts.  Then do a cumulative sum to assign a grouping to the group.  And finally aggregation:

```
select min(id), max(id)
from (select n.*,
             sum(case when prev_id < id then 0 else 1 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from (select n.*,
                   lag(id) over (order by <ordering col>) as prev_n
            from numbers n
           ) n
     ) n
group by grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba690d14629981848a43263a6b65f847) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you, this looks really nice, I will read it and write you back later if I understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that there exists a simpler query than my solution, but for the moment I don't know how to do it

This is gaps-and-islands class problem.
Please note that tables are not sorted by design. You need some kind of column to determine index. `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is probably to satisfy T-SQL but it is not safe.

There are multiple ways to solve it. One of my favourites is [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://modern-sql.com/feature/match_recognize):

```
SELECT f, l 
FROM t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   ORDER BY id
   MEASURES first(c) AS f,
            last(c) AS l
   ONE ROW PER MATCH 
   PATTERN( l+ ge* )
   DEFINE l AS c < NEXT(c) OR NEXT(c) IS NULL,
          ge AS c >= NEXT(c) 
) mr;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2f42970429e4ea3a7004d9531835a53)**

Comment: very nice, thank you. I will read it and comment later if I understand it. Thanks.